# Open source application with Google AdMob ID?

Tags: android, admob

I am currently working on an Android application that will display ads from Google AdMob and have been wondering if I can make this application open-source with its AdMob application id included.

Is this a bad idea? If yes, how would I store it safely? I need to include it in the xml manifest as described [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start):

```
<manifest>
    <application>
        <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
            android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyy"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Just keep that field as blank And include a comment line above it ... If you are including the original Admob Id off course it is a very terrible thing to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make your application open source! Just remember to put sample or "Test Ids" in the app. Do not put Admob Ids from your account as if someone does anything unwanted like clicking repeatedly on your ads may lead you to problems.

- Ad format    Sample ad unit ID

Banner    ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

Interstitial  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712

Interstitial Video  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/8691691433

Rewarded Video  ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917

Native Advanced ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2247696110

Native Advanced Video   ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1044960115

Source: [Google Admob Test Ads][1]

Also, Refer to the code you shared:

```
   <!-- Sample AdMob App ID: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713 -->
```

It is clearly stated about your sample app ID!
[1]: https://developers.google.com/admob/android/test-ads

Comment: Alright, I thought maybe Google has thought of a more intelligent way of storing this information.